# Android check internet connection

Tags: android

on my app i have this method and it tells me if there is internet connection or not, but i would like to know if there is a way to check if it is a good network connection.

```
public static boolean existInternetConnection() {
    boolean booThereConnection = false;
    if (context == null)
        context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        booThereConnection = true;

    return booThereConnection;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. But keep in mind that android always says that a WiFi network is always stronger than mobile network. So my code is for checking the strength of mobile's data.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class Connectivity {
    /*
     * HACKISH: These constants aren't yet available in my API level (7), but I need to handle these cases if they come up, on newer versions
     */
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD=14; // Level 11
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B=12; // Level 9
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP=15; // Level 13
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN=11; // Level 8
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_LTE=13; // Level 11

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }
    /**
     * Check if there is fast connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
    }

    /**
     * Check if the connection is fast
     * @param type
     * @param subType
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
        if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            System.out.println("CONNECTED VIA WIFI");
            return true;
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return false; // ~ 100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
            // NOT AVAILABLE YET IN API LEVEL 7
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
                return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
                return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return false; // ~25 kbps 
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
            // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                return false; 
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: technically if i validate only sub type it will tell me if conection is fast excluding it type?

Comment: @user3586826 yes, you are right. It will only check internet speed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (networkConnectivity())
{
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.anywebsiteyouthinkwillnotbedown.com").openConnection());
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000); //choose your own timeframe
        urlc.setReadTimeout(4000); //choose your own timeframe
        urlc.connect();
        networkcode2 = urlc.getResponseCode();
        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200); // good connection
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        return (false);  //connectivity exists, but no internet.
    }
} else
{
    return false;  //no connectivity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function for this:

```
  public boolean isConnectToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
      NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
      if (info != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
          if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
          }
    }
    return false;
  }
```